# 404 error in callback from bank site to my action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing, payment-gateway

I added Online Payment Gateway to my site that wrote with asp.net mvc 5
in my site need login.
and i wrote an action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult PaymentCallback(string au,int order_id)
{   ... }
```

but when i go to bank site and finishing transaction ,in callback to my site its redirect to address with this:
http://example.com/Transaction/PaymentCallback/?au=70158292914&order_id=27
and iis shows 404 error.
but if i click on address bar in my browser and press enter then it go to my action and routing work correct.
why did this occure and how to correct this?
thanks

Comment: How are you doing the redirect?  To me, it sounds like since this is a GET-only action, whatever verb you are using to redirect to it is not correct.  This would explain why going to it using the URL bar works but your redirect does not.

Comment: I don't redirect.I Send my action address to bank service like this: 
'code'
string callbackAddress = Url.Action("PaymentCallback", "Transaction",null,Request.Url.Scheme,null);
var result = bankService.RequestPayment(orderId, price, callbackAddress);
if ((result > 0)
{
return Redirect("http://www.bankSite.com/pay_invoice/" + result);
}
'code'
then bank site redirct to my site after transaction .

Comment: It sounds like you have a firewall between your bank's server and your development machine that is preventing the callback from happening. When doing workflows like this, the callback typically comes from the *server* of the payment service, not your local browser. For that URL to work, you need an open port on your dev machine and a public DNS name that your bank can resolve (or at least an IP address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by change type of my action from get to post by this attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
```